# how to initialize NameValueCollection with inner NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

After I tried to initialize a NameValueCollection with an inner NameValueCollection, the c# compiler says that has to be NameValueCollection(string,string).

As I thought when I call the Add function when I initialize like this.

- void Add(NameValueCollection c);
- void Add(string name, string value);

Is there any other approach that I can initialize the same on one line, based on NameValueCollection?

The reason is that I have to POST data to an HTTPAddress and I use this [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues?view=netframework-4.7)

Here is my example which won't worked:

```
NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection()
{
   { "key1", "value1"},
   { "key2", new NameValueCollection()
   {
       { "key2sub", "value"}
   }
};
```

Comment: you have to make all parts of the name value collection of the same type <string, string>. This is inherent in `NameValueCollection`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really.The [`UploadValues(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues?view=netframework-4.7) method take a `NameValueCollection`, and a `NameValueCollection` only accepts `string`.

The aim of the method is to transform your data...

```cs
UploadValues("http://www.example.com/", new NameValueCollection()
{
   { "key1", "value1" },
   { "key2", "value2" }
};
```

... into the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

If you want to send more information, you can put a delimited string as the value for one of your keys, and then split it apart again at the other end.

```cs
UploadValues("http://www.example.com/", new NameValueCollection()
{
   { "key1", "value1" },
   { "key2", "value2,value3,value4" }
};
```

Which should produce something like:

```
http://www.example.com/?key1=value1&key2=value2,value3,value4
```

But the best solution is as [@hmnzr said in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43764178/590382) (now-deleted), to avoid `NameValueCollection` entirely and upload a custom object serialized as JSON using the [`UploadString(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstring?view=netframework-4.7) method.

Comment: I wouldn't use the NameValueCollection to accomplish my task, but thx!